# PowerShell hangs - no response to keyboard actions

Tags: powershell, window

PowerShell hangs - no response to keyboard actions.
Do CD - ok
Do httpd.exe - Apache service starts OK,
but then Powershell just hangs.
Can only close window, but then Apache service stops.
Same on all versions of PowerShell

[image]

Comment: Why would `httpd` return? :) Check out `Start-Process`

Comment: Also, the preferred way is to install and control Apache as a _Windows service_ - see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html

Comment: Thanks, but - from "readMe.txt" from Apache Lounge site.Run and test
------------

  Open a command prompt window and cd to the c:\Apache24\bin folder.
  
  To Start Apache in the command prompt type:
  
    >httpd.exe
  
  Press Enter. If there are any errors it will tell you. 
  Warnings will not stop Apache from working, they do need to be addressed none the less. 
  If there are no errors the cursor will sit and blink on the next line. 
  
  You can test your installation by opening up your Browser and typing in the address:
  
     http://localhost

Comment: Problem resolved. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

**[Running Apache as a Console Application](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#wincons)**

> Running Apache as a service is usually the recommended way to use it,
> but it is sometimes easier to work from the command line, especially
> during initial configuration and testing.
>
> To run Apache from the command line as a console application, use the
> following command:
>
> ```
> httpd.exe
> ```
>
> **Apache will execute, and will remain running until it is stopped by pressing Control-C.**

Run the program *asynchronously* as follows:

```
Start-Process -Filepath .\httpd.exe
```

Another option: [Running Apache as a Service](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#winsvc)…